# mysql select distinct where clause

Tags: mysql, join

I have this table, and I want to select all distinct  user_id values where there is both an event='AAAAAAAAAA' and event ='XXXXXXXXXX' (i.e. only result should be user_id=123456789)

```
unique_row_id  user_id          event       event_timestamp
----------------------------------------------------------------
0              123456789        AAAAAAAAAA  2010-01-20 15:00:00
1              123456789        abcdefghij  2010-01-20 15:00:05
2              123456789        XXXXXXXXXX  2010-01-20 15:00:15
3              987654321        AAAAAAAAAA  2010-01-20 16:00:00
4              987654321        abcdefghij  2010-01-20 16:00:05
5              987654321        abcdefghij  2010-01-20 16:00:15
6              111111111        XXXXXXXXXX  2010-01-20 16:01:00
7              111111111        XXXXXXXXXX  2010-01-20 16:01:05
8              111111111        XXXXXXXXXX  2010-01-20 16:01:15
```

I've tried both:

```
SELECT distinct user_id from mydata where event='AAAAAAAAAA' and event='XXXXXXXXXX'
```

which gives me an empty result set, and

```
SELECT distinct user_id from mydata where event='AAAAAAAAAA' or event='XXXXXXXXXX'
```

which gives me everything.  Any suggestions - I'm guessing I need to go down the 'join' road here do I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select user_id from mydata where event='AAAAAAAAAAA'
union
select user_id from mydata where event='XXXXXXXXXXX';
```

This will select both lists (users w/ AAA, users w/ XXX), and then merge them together, removing duplicate rows.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Much better than the `SELECT ... WHERE EXISTS (...)` query that I was writing. ;)

Comment: actually, it's wrong because it does "either" and not "both". revising now :)

Comment: select distinct user_id from(
select user_id from mydata where event='AAAAAAAAAAA'
union
select user_id from mydata where event='XXXXXXXXXXX';
)

Comment: but how about UNION with more than two events.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it with a subquery:

```
select distinct user_id
from mydata m
where event = 'AAAAAAAAAA'
and exists (
  select 1
  from mydata
  where user_id = m.user_id
  and event = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The conditions on the WHERE clause are only applicable on a single row at a time. 
In order to check two rows, you have to use JOIN:

```
SELECT distinct a.user_id 
FROM mydata a, mydata b 
WHERE a.event='AAAAAAAAAA' AND b.event='XXXXXXXXXX' AND a.user_id = b.user_id
```

If you know that an event can only appear once per user, you can use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM mydata 
WHERE event in ('AAAAAAAAAA', 'XXXXXXXXXX')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count(user_id)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT user_id
FROM
    my_table AS outer_table
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            my_table AS inner_table_A
        WHERE
            inner_table_A.user_id = outer_table.user_id AND
            inner_table_A.event = 'AAAAAAAAAA'
    ) AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            my_table AS inner_table_B
        WHERE
            inner_table_B.user_id = outer_table.user_id AND
            inner_table_B.event = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this...

```
SET @events := 'AAAAAAAAAA,XXXXXXXXXX';

SELECT user_id 
FROM mydata
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT event ORDER BY event SEPARATOR ',') = @events;
```