# MySQL Select distinct with dynamic where clauses

Tags: php, mysql

I have a parser to create dynamic queries based on a form input but now I need to select DISTINCT on the field `backend_hotels_id` but still return the entire rows (i.e. what SELECT * would do)

One of my dynamic queries is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `packages_sorted_YHZ` WHERE
(
    `hotel_country` = 'Antigua and Barbuda'
    AND `hotel_city` IN
    (
        'Bolans','Mamora Bay','Saint Philip','St. John\'s'
    )
)OR(
    `hotel_country` = 'Aruba' 
    AND `hotel_city` IN 
    (
        'Oranjestad','Palm/Eagle Beach'
    )
)
AND `package_type` = '9'
AND `date_start` >= '2012-1-25' AND `date_start` <= '2012-12-19'
AND `hotel_score_title` <= '4'
AND `day` IN ('1','2','3','5','6','7')
AND `package_duration` IN ('5','6','7','8','9')
AND `adults_only` = 'y'
AND `price_per_pax_after_tax` <= '10000'
ORDER BY  `deal_score` DESC, `date_start` DESC 
LIMIT 0,3;
```

The above query returns three entire rows as expected but all from the same hotel.

**I would like to maintain the order on two columns (`deal_score` and `date_start`) and return the entire rows from records with unique `backend_hotels_id`**

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206056/mysql-select-distinct-where-clause) that "The conditions on the WHERE clause are only applicable on a single row at a time. In order to check two rows, you have to use JOIN"

I have a where clause on between 9 columns (above) and 22 columns in some circumstances. As the entire query is created dynamically will I have to create scenarios for each and every possibility? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: I think there is some error in the parenthesis. Probably near the `OR`

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the parenthesis. The actual query is much bigger and I trimmed it down.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get? Max deal_score and date_start for every hotel then sort, then first 3, or a list of first 3 hotels having no more than 1 row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**untested**

You can try something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable
SELECT * FROM `packages_sorted_YHZ` WHERE
(
    `hotel_country` = 'Antigua and Barbuda'
    AND `hotel_city` IN
    (
        'Bolans','Mamora Bay','Saint Philip','St. John\'s')
    )
)OR(
    `hotel_country` = 'Aruba' 
    AND `hotel_city` IN 
    (
        'Oranjestad','Palm/Eagle Beach'
    )
)
AND `package_type` = '9'
AND `date_start` >= '2012-1-25' AND `date_start` <= '2012-12-19'
AND `hotel_score_title` <= '4'
AND `day` IN ('1','2','3','5','6','7')
AND `package_duration` IN ('5','6','7','8','9')
AND `adults_only` = 'y'
AND `price_per_pax_after_tax` <= '10000'
;


SELECT * 
FROM TempTable
WHERE
  `deal_score` = (SELECT MAX(t1.deal_score) FROM TempTable AS t1 WHERE t1.backend_hotels_id = TempTable.backend_hotels_id )
      AND `date_start` = (SELECT MAX(t2.date_start) FROM TempTable AS t2 WHERE t2.backend_hotels_id = TempTable.backend_hotels_id )
    LIMIT 0,3;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable;
```

PS: Depending on your data and indexes you can do it also with subqueries without the temptable for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to determine which row within a group of same backend_hotel_id should be selected?

You can use GROUP BY backend_hotels_id, but I think that the hotel it will show you is arbitrary (or at least you should consider it arbitrary).

Comment: I would like to return the records with the highest `deal_score` and `date_start` value as per the `ORDER BY` clause but each with a `UNIQUE backend_hotels_id`